# Laplace equation in semi-circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$$
\mbox{Solve Laplace's equation for}\ \,\mathrm{u}\left(r,\theta\right)\
\mbox{inside a semi-circle with}\
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle{0 \leq r \le a}
\\[1mm]
\displaystyle{0 \leq \theta \leq \pi}
\end{array}\right.
$$
$$
\mbox{The boundary conditions are}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcccl}
\displaystyle{\mathrm{u}\left(r,0\right)} & \displaystyle{=} & \displaystyle{0}
&&
\\[2mm]
\displaystyle{{\partial\mathrm{u} \over \partial\theta}\left(r,\pi\right)}
& \displaystyle{=} & \displaystyle{U_{0} \over \pi}&&
\\
\displaystyle{\mathrm{u}\left(a,\theta\right)} & \displaystyle{=} &
\displaystyle{\mathrm{g}\left(\theta\right)} & \displaystyle{=} & \displaystyle{{1 \over 2}\,U_{0}
\left(\theta \over \pi\right)^{2}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

**My question :**

How do I go on solving that ? I tried to separate the domain in two to have $3$ homogeneous and $1$ non-homogeneous boundary conditions on each of the two domain in order to use separation of variables but that doesn't seem to be right to do since if I set ${\partial\mathrm{u} \over \partial\theta} = 0$ so that ${\partial\mathrm{u} \over\partial \theta}\,\left(a, \pi\right) = 0$ on one domain, there will then be a discontinuity at $\,\mathrm{u}\left(a,\pi\right)$ because $\,\mathrm{g}\left(\pi\right) \neq 0$.

Comment: Where exactly should $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}=U_0/\pi$?

Comment: @Ian Sorry I forgot that! It is true on the line $(r, \pi)$. I corrected for that in my question :)

Comment: Is there any BC on $(b,\theta)$? I do see the problem at $(a,\pi)$, though this can be managed with some care...

Comment: @Ian Oups last mistake I made : $r$ is between $0$ and $a$ and not $a$ and $b$. And there are only 3 BC.

Comment: Should the solution be bounded as r goes to 0? It turns out that this itself is effectively a boundary condition because of the properties of Bessel functions.

Comment: @Ian Yes, the solution must be bounded as $r$ goes to 0.

Comment: Yeah, that will wind up creating an effective boundary condition for the radial part of the solution when you do the separation of variables. Anyway, try setting up the separation of variables and see what you get...

Comment: @Ian I want a continuous solution so how can I separate my domain to be able to solve using separation of variables? There will be definitely a problem if I set $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} (r, \pi) = 0$ because it will not be continious with the non-homogeneous BC $u(a, \theta) = g(\theta)$ at $(a, \pi)$. How do I even begin the problem if I can't have 3 non-homogeneous BC?

Comment: The domain is already in "separable form", in the sense that it is a "polar rectangle" $[0,a] \times [0,\pi]$. So you should attempt to solve the polar Laplace equation using separation of variables.

Comment: @Ian If I pose $u = R\Theta$, I get $\frac{r^2 R'' + r R'}{R} = - \frac{\Theta'}{\Theta} = \lambda = \pm k^2$. If I take $\lambda > 0$, I get $\Theta(\theta) = Acos(k\theta) + Bsin(k\theta)$. The first homogeneous condition in $\theta$ i.e. $u(r,0) = 0$ gives me $A = 0$ but the other condition is non-homogeneous ($\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}(r, \pi) = \frac{U_0}{\pi}$) and cannot be used to find the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$. What I get if I use it is $Bkcos(k\pi) = \frac{U_0}{\pi}$ which I cannot do anything about.

Comment: You can't expect a separable solution to satisfy auxiliary conditions (i.e. ICs or BCs); at the very least you have to put together a superposition of separable solutions to satisfy any auxiliary conditions. You are also encountering one of the annoying issues about separation of variables for non-homogeneous problems: you usually have to modify the formulation of the problem to force the BCs to be homogeneous at the cost of making the equation inhomogeneous.

Comment: In other words, you make an ansatz, usually of the form $u=f+g$ where $f$ is a function you choose yourself which satisfies the inhomogeneous BCs while $g$ is still unknown and is assumed to satisfy homogeneous BCs. Then $g$ satisfies an inhomogeneous version of your original DE (hopefully with an inhomogeneity that you can manage). In this case that DE is $\Delta g = -\Delta f$. Can you find one function $f$ to satisfy your BCs? I can see one (although it has a bit of a singularity at $r=0$).

Comment: @Ian Intuitively, I would take $f = \frac{U_0}{\pi}\theta$ because that removes the inhomogeneity on $(r, \pi)$ so that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}(r,\pi) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}(r,\pi)  - \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}(r,\pi)  = 0$. It seems also to preserve the homogeneous BC $u(r,0) = 0$ so that $g(r,0) = 0$ and $\Delta g$ = 0. However, I don't see any problems with singularity, did I make a mistake?

Comment: I disagree, I'd be inclined to use $f=\frac{1}{2} U_0 \frac{\theta^2}{\pi^2}$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=U_0 \theta/\pi^2$ which is $U_0/\pi$ at $\theta=\pi$. This will satisfy all your BCs, except that it has the pathological property of not being defined at $r=0$. Presumably that problem somehow washes out in the identification of $g$. You will have $\Delta g = -\frac{U_0}{\pi^2 r^2},g=0$ for $\theta=0,r=a$, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}=0$ for $\theta=\pi$, and $g$ should be bounded as $r \to 0$.

Comment: @Ian Yes I agree with you I just confused $f$ with its derivative. Ok so now how do I solve the PDE $\Delta g = -\frac{U_0}{\pi^2 r^2}$? I tried to use separation of variable but I get $\frac{r^2 R'' + r R'}{R} = - \frac{\Theta''}{\Theta} - \frac{U_0}{\pi^2 R\Theta}$. It doesn't seem I can use the trick of setting the equality to a constant $\lambda$, or am I mistaken?

Comment: You need to expand $-\frac{U_0}{\pi^2 r^2}$ into the eigenfunction basis in order to use the separation of variables trick.

Comment: @Ian Could you explain a little further? I don't understand what "eigenfunction basis" mean. All I know involving eigenvalues and eigenfunctions is that in the context of Laplace's equation, eigenfunctions are the separable solutions associated with each eigenvalue $\lambda_n$.

Comment: I'm saying that to solve the inhomogeneous equation $\Delta g = -\frac{U_0}{\pi^2 r^2}$, you first find the eigenfunctions of $\Delta$ which satisfy your boundary conditions, and then you need to write $-\frac{U_0}{\pi^2 r^2}$ as a (possibly infinite) linear combination of those eigenfunctions. If this can be done then substituting it back into the original PDE after eigenfunction expansion gives a system of equations for the coefficients of the solution.

Comment: For example, if you wanted $u''=f$ on $(0,1)$ subject to $u(0)=0,u(1)=0$ then you would take an expansion of $f$ into $\sin(n \pi x)$, with coefficients $a_n$. Then the equation tells you that if $b_n$ are the coefficients of $u$ in a sine expansion, then $-n^2 \pi^2 b_n=a_n$. If $f$ could not be sine expanded then this approach would fail.

Comment: @Ian I have to admit I'm a little confused here :) We've never seen how to solve any equation $\Delta u \neq 0$ in class. Now that I look at the solutions, they are doing it in quite a uncommon way :  they first divide the domain like this : [domain](http://imgur.com/a/OvtsM) with two non-homo. BCs on the first one and 3 homo. BCs on the other. To solve the first sub domain, they only use the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$. The choice for this particular splitting and the fact that $\lambda = 0$ is sufficient to solve the first domain seems to be coming out of nowhere. Can you see why it's working?

Comment: In an other example that is almost identical, they directly search for solutions of the type $u=R\Theta$. They don't split the domain into two but they find the new domain (with now 3 homogeneous BC) of $g$ by saying that $g = u - f$ where $f$ is the solution $R\Theta$ where $R$ and $\Theta$ are found by solving $\frac{r^2 R'' + r R'}{R} = -\frac{\Theta''}{\Theta} = \lambda$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$. This method seems to work on the current problem too. Either way, the solution they find is $f = \frac{U_0}{\pi}\theta$. If this is correct, I have no idea why this works.